# i3blocks (i3wm) - use a sudo command

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I'm configuring my i3blocks for i3wm, and I can't seem to be able to execute sudo command like:

```
[update-notifier]
label=UPDATE
command=sudo ~/.i3/scripts/update-notifier.sh
interval=once
```

inside the update-notifier.sh file I have this:

```
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
```

plus some echo for formatting the i3blocks bar.
I've tried this:

- `command=sudo ~/.i3/scripts/update-notifier.sh` with and without sudo with the apt-get -> The script doesn't launch
- `command=sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` -> the command isn't executed
- `command=~/.i3/scripts/update-notifier.sh` with sudo with the apt-get -> the script launch, the i3bar is properly formatted, but the apt-get isn't executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have sudo configured so it doesn't ask for a password to your user with the apt-get command? Maybe your command is running but it asks for a password and it fails.

I was abled to accomplish what you're trying to do by allowing my user to run apt-get with sudo without password adding this to the `/etc/sudoers` file:

```
<my-user> <my-host> = (root) NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/apt-get
```

And then adding a block with the `command` property set like your second option:

```
command=sudo apt-get update
```

And verified it works by reloading i3 and checking the timestamp of my latest update with:

```
stat -c %y /var/lib/apt/periodic/update-success-stamp
```

Which showed a recent update being successfully done recently:

```
2015-10-13 08:29:30.996348567 -0430
```